# How make a background image fit all screen sizes but allow vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, background

I've looked around the internet and found a load of tutorials that allow you to create a background that fits all screen resolutions. However, I would just like a background where it fits the width of the page and allows the visitor to scroll down the image without having a fixed position...Is this possible?

Comment: yes you can used to background-size:100% auto; helpfull link is http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: thanks a lot! This won't be compatible in older browsers though?

Comment: Then you can define like this img{width:100%;height:auto}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this link

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

as others said,you can try

```
background-size:100% auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

A background that fits all screens and can be scrolled could be a repeating one like a texture:

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url(path_to/texture.png) repeat;
}
```